# I am having trouble compiling Super Mario 64

Tags: command-line, compiling, error-handling

So, just a bit of context. I have no prior experience with using Linux command lines, so I am completely inept when it comes to this kind of thing.

Anyways, I was trying to use the Super Mario 64 Decompilation Project that recently came out, along with a tutorial on how to bake the code into a ROM file, so that I can start making my own little modifications and working with the game until I eventually start making bigger and better stuff with it, which in turn will hopefully result in a great ROM hack. At worst, I just end up having a bit of fun with the source code.

Anyways, here's the video tutorial for it. https://youtu.be/rQVpfWYT0eg?t=314

My problem arises when I have to type the "make" command. Now, another thing, in the screenshot below, I added "sudo" before the chmod. I did this because I heard that makes it available for all users to use (even though I am only using one user and it SHOULD be admin, but it just doesn't work for some reason, so if anybody could help me out with that too, that would be really nice).

Anyways, my problem arises once I type in the "make" command, it gives me this little error (which is also shown in the screenshot below): Makefile.split:150: *** multiple target patterns.  Stop.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/75YWK.png

Comment: Although it's an old game, I do not believe it has been re-licensed as open-source.  Here at AskUbuntu we don't answer questions that support the use of piracy.  Please see the [meta](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3600/questions-that-refer-to-using-or-installing-ripped-pirated-software) topic regarding this for more info.

Comment: @Nmath Ubuntu has at least two n64 emulators available. Unless the software license explicitly prohibits decompiling, I don't think this would be an issue so long as the decompiled rom is not published. Your link mentions illegally downloaded software and the decomp project says that you have to provide your own file of the game to decompile into a usable rom.